# Auto login from credentials based in the URL

Tags: c#, webforms, .net-4.0

c#, .net4, webforms

I'm building if someone forgets a password. A system admin can send a link to the customers email, they can click it, it logs in, and forces them to update their profile. I have everything working and verifying. Now I don't understand (still reading) on how to make 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true; after my method returns true that the person is verified and allow the information from the url log that person in. I know I'm missing something, or not understanding how it works.

Either way, thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide some code - what your method where you want to set `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true;` looks like?

Comment: you want to pass the username and the reset password in the url query string and take that the send to your login request, but doing so is not secure, unless you encode/encrypt the query string, and make it unreadable to the end-user. You must also consider other security concerns which I have not posted here.

Comment: That I have covered. It's encrypted. Just looking at the URL you wouldn't know what it is, Vignesh.N

Comment: I thought that I just needed it set FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(verifiedUser, true); But User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false

Comment: I see. If I refreshed the page. I was able to login.. odd.. like it's not seeing it the first time it loads

Comment: where is your code, that will help us help you...

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs this

```
if (verifiedUser != "0")
{
    //if user is verified
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(verifiedUser, true);
    var LoginType = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Works for my issue.